# Designing a Hierarchical Application with Edit/Add Functionality

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, design-patterns, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller

Take a simple application that stores recipes and ingredients.  The application should allow for recipes to be added, deleted and edited (simply renamed).  For each recipe, ingredients can be added, deleted, and edited (name and some other basic details).  Each ingredient also has some other details than can be displayed.

This clearly seems hierarchical, so I begin with a UINavigationController. I start by displaying a list of recipes, which allows drill-down to the ingredients, and drill-down to the ingredient's details.

But there doesn't seem a simple way to provide this and **also** the add/edit/delete functionality.  Take the top-level Recipes screen.  I have one 'spot' to place a button (the right side of the navigation item at the top of the screen - the left side will be for the 'back' button).  If I make this an 'add' button, then how can a user rename an existing recipe?  If it's an 'edit' button, then I can display the delete icons, and maybe make selection of a recipe display a screen to change the name (instead of drilling down to ingredients), but now I have no way to add a new recipe.

I considered using a bottom toolbar, but

a) this uses a lot of real estate for a simple button

b) if the toolbar is added to a view in the navigation controller, then it is added to all views in the navigation hierarchy.  This implies that the actions in that toolbar do not change (e.g. Apple's email application, where the toolbar always includes the 'compose' button, regardless of where you are in the navigation hierarchy).  It seems to be at a 'higher level' and not tied to the current view.

Is there a standard pattern to observe here?  And any examples of well designed apps that include a hierarchical display of data with the ability to add/edit/delete at all levels?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the design of the Contacts app.

The root navigation view has a right bar button for adding new recipes. You have a table view that lists the previously added recipes below. A tap on a cell gives you details about the recipe. On the detail navigation view you have an edit button as a right bar button. When you use edit you get the option of deleting the recipe and changing the ingredients. That brings up a new navigation view that has a new item right bar button and a list of ingredient items in the table view.

Similarly, you can get as many levels as you require.

An example of the hierarchy:

1. Recipes view with an add button in the right toolbar item and recipe item cells. Tap on a recipe cell pushes detail view 2.
2. Recipes detail view with edit button for edit mode. In edit mode you have a delete recipe button and an ingridients button that pushes view 3.
3. Ingredients view with an add button and ingridient item cells. Tap on a cell pushes view 4.
4. Ingredient detail view with an edit button. And so forth.

That would be my general idea, but you modify it for your specific situation. Hope the edit clarifies things a bit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried reading this a few times and don't follow your flow.  The contacts app has one list only, not a hierarchy.  When I select a contact, I am taken to tis details, with an edit button.  But when I click on a recipe, I will be taken to a **list* of ingredients, which in turn can be selected to drill down further.

Comment: Technically the contacts app has a level above (Groups), but there is no add/edit funtionality on that view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Apples sample code, Core Recipes app. Its exactly what you describe.It uses CoreData and is a great way to learn about it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html

Changed link to iPhone Version

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded and tried this example.  I find it very awkward from a user experience POV.  The number of steps and screens involved in simply adding an ingredient to an existing recipe is far from ideal, as is their implementation of using an 'Add Ingredient' row, which I find non-obvious.  The fact that the Apple example uses this design makes me think that it is simply a limitation of the framework, though it might also be a design choice based on a subtle difference in user focus.  I can elaborate further on what I think are it's shortcomings but it's probably off topic.